# is it possible to create array of TableRow objects?

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in creating Android apps. If this question is silly I am so sorry. Is it possible to create an array of `tablerow` `objects`?
If this is possible, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, but it depends on what are you trying to achieve. You could simply define an `ArrayList<TableRow>` and add them via the `.add()` method. But usually, `TableRow`s are meant to be within a `TableLayout`. This latter is basically the equivalent to the `<table>` HTML statement, which defines a table, and the `TableRow` would be the `<tr>` statement.

You'll find more info about those concepts:

- [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) about `ArrayList`s.
- [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) about `TableRow`s.
- [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) about `TableLayout`s.

Comment: The simplest way would be creating a `Class` where you would define as many objects as you need, for example, call it `MyClass` and define inside `String a`, `int b`, `Boolean c`, and define your array like `ArrayList<MyClass>`, this way you can have "a n-dimensional array"

Comment: can i have like this TableRow[][] tr=new TableRow[2][4]

Comment: That would be the Java way (nothing to do with the Android SDK) but yes, properly defined that would work.

Comment: then in android SDK this "TableRow[][] tr=new TableRow[2][4] " wont work...right??

Comment: Sure, any array of any permitted object might be defined, just try it.

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a difference between ViewGroups (such as TableRow) which are nested vs. an ArrayList of objects which do not necessarily have any layout relationship to each other.  A nested layout can be walked to find its elements, while you could consider an ArrayList of them as a sort of cache of that result, which depending on your application may or may not advantageous.